# Сравнение дат\времени в Python

Tags: python, время, iso8601

Я с API получаю случайное время в формате ISO8601 (2021-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z)
Как с помощью Python проверить, значение полученного времени позже или раньше от времени в настоящий момент минус 2 недели. Другими словами, мне нужно только то время, которое входит в промежуток от сегодня, до двух недель назад.

Comment: Разделите задачу на подзадачи: 1) Получить дату 2) Вычесть из даты период 3) Сравнить даты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ничего не поменялось, то распаристь стандартной библиотеой `datetime` формат `ISO8601` не получится.

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

> Caution This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of datetime.isoformat(). A more full-featured ISO 8601 parser, dateutil.parser.isoparse is available in the third-party package dateutil.

Поэтому можно воспользоваться методом `strptime()` из `datetime`-модуля

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def check_period(datetime_check:str) -> bool:
    to_datetime = datetime.strptime(datetime_check, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    if (to_datetime + timedelta(weeks=2)) > datetime.now():
        return True
    return False
```

проверяем:

```py
dates = [
    "2021-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z", # False
    "2022-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z", # True
]

for date in dates:
    print(f"{date}, возвращено из функции {check_period(date)}")
```

вывод:

```
2021-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z, возвращено из функции False
2022-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z, возвращено из функции True
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне понравилось то, как вы составили условие if. Я как-то не додумался до этого

Answer (score 2):

Если вы получаете время в формате ISO8601, c использованием UTC смещения, то и работать дальше неверное захотите в этом формате. Поэтому:

```
dt1=datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
dt3=datetime.datetime.now().utcnow()
dt4=dt3-datetime.timedelta(days=14)
print(dt1,dt4)
if dt4>dt1: 
    print('Вышли за диапазон')
else:
    print('Остались в  диапазоне')
```

Результат:

```
2021-01-29 21:33:04.836603 2022-01-21 10:38:34.406008
Вышли за диапазон
```

Если задать

```
dt1=datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-29T21:33:04.836603Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

то результат получим:

```
2022-01-29 21:33:04.836603 2022-01-21 10:41:59.984071
Остались в  диапазоне
```

Если же захотите сначала перейти к датам без UTC смещения, то все делается по аналогии, но вместо метода .utcnow() используете метод .now().